# live camera video streaming using gstreamer on to web browser

Tags: browser, gstreamer, h.264, http-live-streaming

I would like to stream live camera capture on to web browser using gstreamer where camera frame comes from appsrc.

suggest me the best way to proceed.

Pra-win

Comment: I'm trying do the same thing, someone has done with node.js server. http://delog.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/stream-live-webm-video-to-browser-using-node-js-and-gstreamer/

Answer (score 2):

In gstreamer alone you will not find a sink plugin that will be able to serve your purpose (believe me, Ive been looking) you will need a server.

If you like gstreamer, I can suggest one: **gst-rtsp-server**. It integrates seamlessly to your gstreamer and sets up a RTSP server in a port/address defined by you. (however it is not included in gstreamer, You'll have to compile/install it separately.)

Comment: Thanks for reply. How could directly read rtsp video data in html page  .

Comment: Could u provide  one example to use h264 video on web browser.
Gstreamer pipe line and video tag in html.